# How to do 'groupby' a column value (str) and return n unique rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
df1=
     col1 col2 col3 value
      A   B     AB   20
      C   C     AB   10
      D   C     AB   90
      E   E     AA   10
      F   E     AA   20
      G   F     AA   10
```

I want to groupby column 'col3' and return two rows for each col3 value(random).something like this.

```
    df1=
     col1 col2 col3 value
      A   B     AB   20

      D   C     AB   90

      F   E     AA   20

      G   F     AA   10
```

Comment: Use `df.sample(frac=1).groupby('col3').head(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('col3').apply(lambda x: x.sample(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

OR with slightly better syntax:

```
df.groupby('col3').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample,n=2).reset_index(drop=True)
```